# Processing a CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to make a R-script to get a better overview of my CSV bank data.
My goal is to group all my costs into different categories. 
For instance, I want McDonalds and Burger King go into “resturantsCosts”.
Food market costs from Kaisers, Lidl, and Rewe shall go to “foodCompaniesCosts”.
Subscription costs from Vattenfall, Gasag, and Vodaphone shall go to “subscriptionCosts”.

My difficulty right now is to process the information.
Here are some inquires examples from my CSV file:

"01554 MCDONALDS", "REWE251", "11379 BURGER KING ALEX BHF", "KAISERS TENGELMANN 82139*DE", "KAISERS TENGELMANN 82124*DE"

My idea was to split each inquire into a list, remove all numbers, and make all letters small.
For instance “KAISERS TENGELMANN 82124*DE” would be:
"kaisers" "tengelmann" "*de"

Then was my idea to match the result into different premade lists to see if one of the words are in there. Example, foodCompanies list contains the following words: "kaisers", "lidl", "rewe".
Because the foodCompanies list contains the word “kaisers” and the inquire contains the word “kaisers” there would be a match. However, I having difficulties getting it to work.
Could somebody help me?

EDIT: The problem is not to read data. The problem is to process data. I can read all the companies and costs and they are stored in "company" and "costs". It is the following that doesn't work correctly:

```
temp <- tolower( trimws( gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', company[i]) ) ) 
temp <- strsplit(temp, " ")
```

For instance, set "KAISERS TENGELMANN 82139*DE" as the variable company. The I get the following result:

> "c(\"kaisers\", \"tengelmann\", \"*de\")"

Here is my full code:

```
mydata = read.csv2("mydata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote = "\"",
                   dec = ",", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

company = mydata[[6]]
costs = mydata[[9]]

foodCompanies = c("kaisers", "lidl", "rewe")
resturants = c("burger king", "mcdonalds")
subscriptions = c("vattenfall", "gasag", "vodaphone")

foodCompaniesCosts = c()
resturantsCosts = c()
subscriptionCosts = c()

for (i in 1:length(company)){
  temp <- tolower( trimws( gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', company[i]) ) )
  temp <- strsplit(temp, " ")

  if(any ( temp %in% foodCompanies ) == TRUE) {foodCompaniesCosts <- c(foodCompaniesCosts, costs[i])
  } else if(any ( temp %in% resturants ) == TRUE) {resturantsCosts <- c(resturantsCosts, costs[i])
  } else if(any ( temp %in% subscriptions ) == TRUE) {subscriptionCosts <- c(subscriptionCosts, costs[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, convert `temp` to a `data.frame` before your `if` statements begin. Specifically, add the line `temp <- data.frame(temp)`.